# ftp_putI llegal PORT command in

Tags: php, ftp

Открываею соединение через `ftp_connect` (на выходе ресурс)
Логинюсь через `ftp_login` (на выходе `true`)
Заливаю файл через `ftp_put` (на выходе `false`)

Если использовать пассивный режим

```
ftp_pasv($open, true);
```

Тогда на сервере файл появляется но он пустой.

- Файл который заливаю существует.
- Путь куда заливаю существует.
- DrWeb отключен.
- Брандмауер отключен.
- Работаю локально под Open Server.
- Доступа к логам сервера куда заливается файл нету.

На хостинге код работает, на локалке нет.

Подскажите где искать?